# Laravel Unsupported operand types in Auth::attempt()

Tags: php, laravel

I have an odd issue with Laravel. I have a resource controller setup to receive authentication request via POST request however when I call

```
Auth::attempt(Input::only('username', 'password'));
```

I get this error

```
maint_mgr/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)
Unsupported operand types

* @param string $class
* @return array
*/
function class_uses_recursive($class)
{
   foreach (array_merge([$class => $class], class_parents($class)) as $class)
   {
       $results += trait_uses_recursive($class);
   }
```